# Making a http request trough Socks proxy

Tags: delphi, indy, socks

I have a socks proxy and I need to make a HTTP Get request

I tried using indy using this sample ( http://www.indyproject.org/KB/index.html?howdoiuseaproxywithindy.htm ) but I always get the error  :

> Connection closed gracefully.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to handle this is to assign a `TIdIOHandlerStack` component to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property, then assign a `TIdSocksInfo` component to the `TIdIOHandlerStack.TransparentProxy` property, and then configure the `TIdSocksInfo` as needed.

Comment: Actually you need to put TIdSocksInfo in the tidiohandlerstack but your answer led me to the right path!